# Pulling Existing Facebook Canvas Elements through cURL API

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-ads-api

Does anyone know if existing Facebook Canvas Ads can be pulled or edited the API, specifically through cURL?

The documentation, certainly that that's found through search is pretty vapid.

My hope is to be able to pull an existing canvas ad, use that as a template and then create new ones against that. Included within this is the feed ad that launches the canvas experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I actually found the answer to this. You can see canvasses associated with your Facebook Page and the constituent elements by using this cURL code:

```
curl -i -X GET \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<PageID>/canvases?fields=background_color%2Cbody_elements%2Ccanvas_link&access_token=<AccessToken>"
```

These can be easily constructed at:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer